# Deadlock - Use consistent order, what does consistent order mean?

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking, innodb, deadlock

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlocks-handling.html

> When modifying multiple tables within a transaction, or different sets
> of rows in the same table, do those operations in a **consistent order**
> each time. Then transactions form well-defined queues and do not
> deadlock. For example, **organize database operations into functions
> within your application**, or call stored routines, rather than coding
> multiple similar sequences of INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements in
> different places.

I couldn't understand why it says to use functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using functions isn't strictly necessary, but it helps in many code projects to use fewer, well-reviewed code paths so you can encourage the idea of consistent order of data tasks. If locks are acquired in the same order, they don't deadlock.

If the alternative on a large code project is that every developer codes whatever SQL they want in any order they want, there's a higher risk that they use different order of SQL statements because the developers don't coordinate with other developers.

You can in theory achieve the same thing without using functions, but it requires better communication between members of the developers in the team.

Comment: `"If locks are acquired in the same order, they don't deadlock"`. If transaction 1 requires lock A and B (in that order) and transaction 2 (which does different functionality but still needs those 2 locks) also requires lock A and B. Transaction B has to take lock 1°-A and then 2°-B instead of 1°-B and 2°-A to avoid the deadlock, is that what that refers to? That's what I don't understand, the "order".

Comment: If transaction 1 acquires lock A, and transaction 2 wants lock A, then transaction 2 waits. Then 1 acquires B and finishes its work and releases both locks. Then 2 ends it wait, acquires A then B and does its work. They do not deadlock.

Comment: Whereas if they don't use the same order, they can deadlock easily: Transaction 1 acquires A, 2 acquires B. 1 tries to get B but has to wait. Then 2 tries to get A and has to wait. Thus they are both waiting for each other and neither can finish their work. That's the deadlock. It's caused because they request locks in different order.

Comment: thanks @Bill Karwin, does the order to request the locks have to be respected EVEN IF THE TRANSACTIONS do different functionalities?

Comment: Taking into account that, in addition to their functionality, they depend on common locks

Comment: I've explained twice. I'm going to leave you to think about the scenarios. If you think them through, you'll understand it better.